# Insert multiple comma separated columns as a single row in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

i have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl(PackId NVARCHAR(MAX),AmntRemain NVARCHAR(MAX),AmntUsed NVARCHAR(MAX),IsCount NVARCHAR(MAX),IsValue NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #tbl VALUES('1,2','10,20','10,20','1,0','0,1')
```

above table output is

[image]

my concern is how to get output like below

[image]

how to insert data into a table of above table data as all columns individual value as a independent row

Comment: Never insert multiple values in a single column

Comment: This is a bad design. Ideally you can have the data as 2 row in the same table. Else have a separate table to hold this comma separated values as rows and then have a foreign key to map to parent table.

Comment: Why are you storing data in that format in the first place?

Comment: Pretty sure OP is trying to get the data from this bad format into the correct format...

Comment: SQL Server has a `STRING_SPLIT` function since 2016 that returns values as a table. There are various ways to split strings in earlier versions. The problem with *this* table though is that you have *5* different CSV fields, resulting in 2^5 value combinations.

Comment: Are you trying to fix bad data or do you actually want to store the data in this form? Why don't you reload the data from their sources in a correct form? It's not worth cleaning this up unless you have no other way to get to the data.

Comment: @david possibly but how did this bad format come to exist in the database in the first place? Why is the transform not done in the ETL?

Comment: @MartinSmith Who can say, I've had some pretty horrible formats to convert over the years, especially when they come from IoT devices!

Comment: Converting this could be done in TSQL with a split function but it would be much better done in SSIS in a custom script transform.

Answer (score 1):

You should never store your data like this. You should really fix your etl processes and database schema per all the comments on your question.

Using `cross apply(values ...)` to unpivot your data, splitting the strings, and using conditional aggregation to pivot the data back to rows:

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use `string_split()`.

In SQL Server pre-2016, using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden:

```
;with cte as (
  select 
      Id = row_number() over (order by (select null)) /* adding an id to uniquely identify rows */
    , * 
  from #tbl
)
select 
    cte.Id
  , s.ItemNumber
  , PackId     = max(case when u.column_name = 'PackId' then s.item end)
  , AmntRemain = max(case when u.column_name = 'AmntRemain' then s.item end)
  , AmntUsed   = max(case when u.column_name = 'AmntUsed' then s.item end)
  , IsCount    = max(case when u.column_name = 'IsCount' then s.item end)
  , IsValue    = max(case when u.column_name = 'IsValue' then s.item end)
from cte
  cross apply (values ('PackId',PackId),('AmntRemain',AmntRemain),('AmntUsed',AmntUsed),('IsCount',IsCount),('IsValue',IsValue)) u (column_name,column_value)
  cross apply dbo.delimitedsplit8K(u.column_value,',') s
group by cte.Id, s.ItemNumber
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZIFFQX41171

returns:

```
+----+------------+--------+------------+----------+---------+---------+
| Id | ItemNumber | PackId | AmntRemain | AmntUsed | IsCount | IsValue |
+----+------------+--------+------------+----------+---------+---------+
|  1 |          1 |      1 |         10 |       10 |       1 |       0 |
|  1 |          2 |      2 |         20 |       20 |       0 |       1 |
+----+------------+--------+------------+----------+---------+---------+
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)
- [Ordinal workaround for **`string_split()**` - Solomon Rutzky](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2433171)

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert into 2 rows. Try:

```
INSERT INTO #tbl VALUES
('1','10','10','1','0')
,('2','20','20','0','1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just about any parse/split function will do.  The one supplied below also returns an **Item Sequence Number** which can be used to join and the individual elements in an appropriate row.

The number of elements are NOT fixed, one record could have 2 while another has 5.

I should add, if you can't use or want a UDF, it would be a small matter to create an in-line approach.

**Example**

```
Declare @Staging TABLE (PackId NVARCHAR(MAX),AmntRemain NVARCHAR(MAX),AmntUsed NVARCHAR(MAX),IsCount NVARCHAR(MAX),IsValue NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Staging VALUES
 ('1,2','10,20','10,20','1,0','0,1')

Select B.*
 From  @Staging A
 Cross Apply (
                Select PackId     = B1.RetVal
                      ,AmntRemain = B2.RetVal
                      ,AmntUsed   = B3.RetVal
                      ,IsCount    = B4.RetVal
                      ,IsValue    = B5.RetVal
                 From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](A.PackId,',')     B1 
                 Join [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](A.AmntRemain,',') B2 on B1.RetSeq=B2.RetSeq
                 Join [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](A.AmntUsed,',')   B3 on B1.RetSeq=B3.RetSeq
                 Join [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](A.IsCount,',')    B4 on B1.RetSeq=B4.RetSeq
                 Join [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](A.IsValue,',')    B5 on B1.RetSeq=B5.RetSeq
              ) B
```

***Returns***

```
PackId  AmntRemain  AmntUsed    IsCount IsValue
1       10          10          1       0
2       20          20          0       1
```

**The UDF if interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Much faster than str-Parse, but limited to 8K
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't, unless your inserting data from another table you will have to create individual insert statements for each row you want to create.

Comment: yes but if i have more columns then that many of temporary tables i need to create.i think this is not fair.is there any alternative

Comment: Do you have the data in a spreadsheet? If so, you could use the SQL server Import and export wizard to import it straight into a table.